# How to create crontab job in Chef based on a variable values from ruby code

Tags: ruby, variables, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hello I'm new to Chef and Ruby.
I'm trying to make a recipe in Chef 
To create a cron job on a server 
based on a value of a variable that I get inside my ruby code.

```
Gem.clear_paths
node.default["value"] = "nil"
require 'net/http'
ruby_block "do-http-request-with-cutom-header" do
    block do
      Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.html') # => String
      uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
      params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
      uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
      res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      value= res.code
      node["value"] = value
    end
end
if node["value"] == "nil" then
  cron "cassandra repair job" do
    action :delete
  end
else
  cron "cassandra repair job" do
    hour "0"
    minute "55"
    weekday node["value"]
    mailto "root@localhost"
    user "root"
    command "/opt/cassandra/bin/nodetool  repair -par -inc -pr"
  end
end
```

I know that chef has Lazy Evaluation variable method and ruby code is executing on a converge phase, but I can not figure out the way to modify my code.

How can I use lazy evaluation in my code ?

Comment: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/cron

Comment: @RajarshiDas The Q is not about the cron resource but about lazy evaluation, and when you edit a post you should try to fix it as a whole, not just part :)

Comment: [related if not duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424244/using-a-ruby-block-to-assign-variables-in-chef-recipe?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

`node['value'] = value` will create an attribute at the normal level, caveat, it is saved on the node object and stay there forever.

As you're using a volatile attribute coming from external source, you should use `node.run_state['value']` which purpose is to keep transient value during the run.

Now, as you said it, you need to use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation) in your later resources for the value and for the action as you wish a different action depending of the external service return.

Example with update use of run_state here, untested code:

```
node.run_state['value'] = nil
node.run_state['action'] = :delete
require 'net/http'

ruby_block "do-http-request-with-cutom-header" do
    block do
      Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.html') # => String
      uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
      params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
      uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
      res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      value= res.code
      node.run_state['value'] = value
      node.run_state['action'] = :create
    end
end
cron 'cassandra repair job' do
    hour '0'
    minute '55'
    weekday lazy { node.run_state['value'] }
    mailto 'root@localhost'
    user 'root'
    command '/opt/cassandra/bin/nodetool  repair -par -inc -pr'
    action lazy { node.run_state['action'] }
end
```

Using `lazy` on the action parameter is possible since chef 12.4, if you're under this you'll have to craft the resource and run it within the ruby block.

Example crafted from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15790113/3627607) (still untested):

```
ruby_block "do-http-request-with-cutom-header" do
    block do
      Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.html') # => String
      uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
      params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
      uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
      res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      if res.code.nil? 
        r = Chef::Resource::Cron.new "cassandra repair job"
        r.run_action :delete
      else
        r = Chef::Resource::Cron.new "cassandra repair job"
        r.hour "0"
        r.minute "55"
        r.weekday res.code
        r.mailto "root@localhost"
        r.user "root"
        r.command "/opt/cassandra/bin/nodetool  repair -par -inc -pr"
        r.run_action :create
      end
    end
end
```

But at this point, it seems you would better get this information from a custom [`ohai plugin`](https://docs.chef.io/release/ohai-8/#custom-plugins) and use your original code without lazy.

Comment: But this only solve a half of a my problem.  How do I make a condition check on a node.run_state['value']  If I use this constraction no matter what values I'm assigning inside ruby code It will alwayts stays nill  if node.run_state['value'] = "nil" then
    cron "cassandra repair job" do
   action :delete   
    end
else
    cron "cassandra repair job" do
        hour "0"
        minute "55"
 weekday lazy { node.run_state['value'] }
        mailto 'root@localhost'
        user "root"
        command "/opt/cassandra/bin/nodetool  repair -par -inc -pr"
    end
end

Comment: Indeed, you'll had to make the action a temp attribute too. Set to :delete by default and to :create if there's something to do and then use action lazy { node.run_state['action'] } I think

Comment: @user2784340 Updated answer, should do the trick on chef 12.4 and above.